# Having issues with D3 rendering in bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I get a blank screen when the browser tries to render the following code and its json file.  happens both Safari and Chrome. Seems like it renders the SVG in the canvas but not the rest. Am I missing something in the structure? Or should it be run on a server ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
// load the external data from built-in method in D3
   d3.json("datastuff.json", function(data) {

   // after data load then...
    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", 500)
   .attr("height", 500)

   canvas.selectAll("rect")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age * 10; })
       .attr("height", 50)
       .attr("y", function (d,i) {return  i * 50; })
       .attr("fill", "blue")

    })


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is its associated external datastuff.json file.

```
[
{“name”:”Maria”,”age”:30},
{“name”:”Fred”,”age”:50},
{“name”:”Francis”,”age”:12}
]
```

Comment: dou u want load data from external file itself or you did that for example purpose ?

Comment: yes -- would like to load from external file.  Do you see the external file contents shown?

Comment: so you need to run your code from localhost

Comment: This example does not need to run from localhost [See this example...](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714)   just trying understand why or when it should be run from localhost.

Comment: are you seeing any error in browser console?

Comment: No, not seeing errors, just a blank browser.

Comment: are  you checking in console.?

Comment: Yes -- I guess due to the Json file, the files must be hosted on a server.  xmlhttprequest cannot load is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin -- If a CVS or tab delimited file is used as a data source, then a server is not needed to run or host the files.